# Firebase database query orderBy + where in one function

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to archive this but have not managed to do so yet. I assume it is not possible as my app crashes when I try to combine a orderBy with a where in one go.

So my question is: Is it possible? and If yes, how?

My idea would be that I want to order all my posts by creation date where (e.g) the category of the post equals "Memes"

like this

```
Ref().databaseAllPosts().queryOrdered(byChild: DATE).queryEqual(toValue: "Memes", childKey: CATEGORY).queryLimited(toLast: 10)...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `childKey` parameter that you can pass to `queryEqual(toValue:, childKey: )` is actually the **key** of a node. This key is used to disambiguate when there are multiple nodes with the same **value** for the property your order on.

So in your scenario: if there are multiple nodes with the same date, you can pass the key of one of those nodes (in addition to their date value) to get results starting at that specific node.

---

Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property.

In your case, you might be able to combine the values of `date` and `category` into a single `"category_date": "swift_20201211"`, and order/filter on that.

For a longer example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)